# Angularjs pass ui-router controller $scope to data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

i want to pass a `pageTitle` data from ui-router based on a `$stateParams` and then update the title of the page using a directive

ui-router example:

```
.state('index.something.detail', {
        url: '/{type}/{else}',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'tempalte.html',
                controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
                    if ($stateParams.type == "param") {
                        $scope.title = "param";
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Something {{title}}', //NOT WORKING
        },
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: 'Sometgin {{title}}', //IT WORKS
            parent: 'index.something'
        }
    })
```

directive example:

```
function pageTitle($rootScope, $timeout) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            var listener = function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                // Default title - load on Dashboard 1
                var title = 'APP';
                // Create your own title pattern
                if (toState.data && toState.data.pageTitle) title = 'APP | ' + toState.data.pageTitle;
                $timeout(function() {
                    element.text(title);
                });
            };
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', listener);
        }
    }
};
```

angular-breadcrumb pass the data ok

> Something param

but in the pageTitle directive i get

> Something {{title}}

how can i pass the $scope of the ui-router state?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We cannot pass this via `data` setting. The reason is, that the string param in `data {}` is just a string, not a view template. We would need to compile it and pass a scope.

But there is a better solution. Check this [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/xeAGKbKcMSwLBrSz8E0X?p=preview)
Let's have index.html like this:

```
<H1><ui-view name="title" /></H1>

<ul>
  <li><a ui-sref="parent">parent</a>
  <li><a ui-sref="parent.child">parent.child</a>
</ul>

<div ui-view=""></div>
```

And our state can now inject stuff into two locations:

```
.state('state name', {
  ...
  views : {
    "" : {
      // default view
    }
    "title" : {
      template : "parent is setting title inside of index.html"
    }
  }
})
```

Check this [here in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/xeAGKbKcMSwLBrSz8E0X?p=preview)

Also, observe the UI-Router default sample application (doing the same trick) here:

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/

The most important part of the code is [Contact state def](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/sample/app/contacts/contacts.js), there is a small snippet:

```
// You can have unlimited children within a state. Here is a second child
// state within the 'contacts' parent state.
.state('contacts.detail', {    
    ...
     views: {
      // So this one is targeting the unnamed view within the parent state's template.
      '': {
       ...
      },
      // This one is targeting the ui-view="hint" within the unnamed root, aka index.html.
       // This shows off how you could populate *any* view within *any* ancestor state.
      'hint@': {
        template: 'This is contacts.detail populating the "hint" ui-view'
      },
      // This one is targeting the ui-view="menuTip" within the parent state's template.
      'menuTip': {
```

Comment: Hi. Having a problem. Only the first view is set. Others aren't shown.

Comment: @celerno any other details? A link to your question?